# Remove elements from a jquery set

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I get a set of jquery elements

```
var bad_elements = $('.my_elements.bad');
var all_elements = $('.my_elements);
```

var good_elements = ??? How can I do this ??? // $('.my_elements') - $('.my_elements.bad');

Comment: The jQuery documentation is your friend: http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var good_elements = $(".my_elements:not(.bad)");`

Answer (score 1):

Just filter out the bad elements

```
var good = all_elements.filter(function() {
    return !$(this).is(bad_elements);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/48A7u/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have 2 jQuery object, you can use `.not`:

```
var good_elements = all_elements.not(bad_elements);
```

Alternatively, if you want to optimise you code, you could do :

```
var all_elements = $('.my_elements'),
    bad_elements = all_elements.filter('.bad'),
    good_elements = all_elements.not(bad_elements);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can do this, I suppose:

```
all_elements.filter(":not(.bad)");
```

This filters out the bad elements.